# Why is my select not being populated with my MongoDB Collection?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, html-select

In my Meteor app, I am publishing:

```
ForeignVisaTypes = new Mongo.Collection("foreignVisaTypes");

if (Meteor.isServer) {

    Meteor.publish("foreignVisaTypes", function () {
      return ForeignVisaTypes.find();
    });
}
```

...and subscribing to:

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Meteor.subscribe("foreignVisaTypes");
  . . .
}
```

...a Collection which *is* populated with values.

However, this attempt to populate the select is failing:

```
<select name="selvisatype" id="selvisatype" title="Please select a visa type">
    {{#each foreignVisaTypes}}
      <option value={{value}}>{{display}}</option>
    {{/each}}
</select>
```

Why is it failing?

Comment: where you do define the `foreignVisaTypes` helper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not enough to subscribe to a collection. It will not be available directly in spacebars as a helper. So you still need to define a helper to expose it.

Just add this to your client code and things should start working (replace myTemplate with the name of your template):

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
    foreignVisaTypes: function() {
        return ForeignVisaTypes.find();
    }
});
```